# Replace item in list with list

Tags: r, list

Given a list `Z <- list("a"=1, "b"=2, "d"=3)`, how do I replace, for example, items 1 and 3 with lists so that the final object is, for example:

```
> Z
$a
[[1]] 
[1] TRUE
[[2]] 
[1] "apple"

$b
[1] 2

$d
[[1]] 
[1] TRUE
[[2]] 
[1] "apple"
```

Using `replace(Z, c(1,3), list(TRUE, "apple")`) instead replaces item 1 with `TRUE` and item 3 with `"apple"`, as does using the assign operator `Z[c(1,3)] <- list(TRUE, "apple")`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it...

```
Z <- list("a"=1, "b"=2, "d"=3)

Z[c(1,3)] <- list(list(TRUE,"apple"))

Z
$`a`
$`a`[[1]]
[1] TRUE

$`a`[[2]]
[1] "apple"


$b
[1] 2

$d
$d[[1]]
[1] TRUE

$d[[2]]
[1] "apple"
```

Or `Z <- replace(Z,c(1,3),list(list(TRUE,"apple")))` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `lapply`.  I spent about 10-15 minutes fumbling over the question, and the list replacements kept getting truncated at only the first element.  The problem is that I was using `ifelse` to decide whether to return a list, or the original element.  Switching to a formal `if` `else` statement fixed that problem.

```
Z <- list("a"=1, "b"=2, "d"=3)
lst <- list(TRUE, "apple")
indices <- c(1, 3)
output <- lapply(Z, function(x) {
    if (x %in% indices) { lst } else { x }
})

output

$a
$a[[1]]
[1] TRUE

$a[[2]]
[1] "apple"


$b
[1] 2

$d
$d[[1]]
[1] TRUE

$d[[2]]
[1] "apple"
```